# Can I add a cron job without editing a file?

Tags: cron

I want to write a script that add a cron job to my crontab but without user intervention like editing a file using `crontab -e`. Is there a way to programatically manipulate the cron jobs from command line? Any suggestion on how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `crontab` uses the values of the `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` variables to determine the program which will edit the crontab - the variables can contain, for example, the path to a script, or shell commands, using which you can programmatically edit it. See for example, http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179445/70524 using this to edit suoders.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To install a crontab:

```
echo "1 1  * * *  test" | crontab -
```

should do the trick.

NOTICE that this **substitutes** the whole crontab. You have to save the value it had with `crontab -l` if you just want to add/edit things. For example

```
(crontab -l && echo "1 1  * * *  test") | crontab -
```

will add the line to your crontab.

Comment: "crontab -l" produces on some linux distros a warning message if you have no crontabs. So this will concatenate the warning as a cronjob. Use "crontab -l 2>/dev/null" instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
crontab -l | some-editing-command | EDITOR=cat crontab -e
```

The first part of the pipe lists the current crontab, the second part is supposed to modify it in a sensible way, and the third part reinstalls it using `cat` as the "editor", as suggested by @muru.

Comment: You do not need to redefine `EDITOR`. Just do: `crontab -l | some-editing-command | crontab -`